# Is there a way to pass a variable from python script to bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I have multiple python codes that need to be executed sequentially. Ive done so by using abash script.

```
#! /bin/sh
clear
echo "Test 1: Database Comparison"
python3 databasecomparison.py
python3 error.py

echo "Test 2: Conflicting ARFCNs"
python3 conflictingARFCNs.py

echo "Test 3: Conflicting Cell IDs"
python3 conflictingCID.py

echo "Test 4: Lonesome Location ID"
python3 conflictingLAC.py

echo "Test 5: Empty Neighbour List"
python3 neighbour.py

echo "Test 6: Missing IMSI"
python3 IMSI.py

echo "The tests are complete!"
notify-send "COMPLETED!"
```

Now, my python code of error.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess as s


file = open("doubt.txt","r") 
Counter = 0
  
# Reading from file 
Content = file.read() 
CoList = Content.split("\n") 
  
for i in CoList: 
    if i: 
        Counter += 1
          
#print("This is the number of lines in the file") 
#print(Counter) 

if Counter > 1:
    print("There is some erroneous value. Please restart the scanner")
    s.call(['notify-send','Alert!','There is some erroneous value. Please restart the scanner'])
```

I want to pass the value of the variable Counter from the python code to the bash script such that I can execute:

```
if Counter > 1
then break
fi
```

However, I am unable to pass the variable Counter.
Ive looked up the existing solution on stackoverflow but truth b told, I've been unable to understand any of them. Please help.

Comment: Why are you tagging this question bash when you don't have a bash script? Or do you run it explicitly with `bash SCRIPTNAME`? I ask because your #! line says `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Any output from stdout can be captured into a bash variable. A regular `print` will print to stdout

**hello.py**

```
print('hello')
```

**bash**

```
RESULT=`python3 hello.py`
echo $RESULT  # hello
```

Comment: Thankyou for your prompt response.

Comment: This is returning the following error: ./deepscan.sh: 6: ./deepscan.sh: python3 error.py: not found

Comment: @buttercup : If you have a new problem, don't discuss it in a comment, but create a new question for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make your bash script one that takes command line arguments. Then, in your python script, do a subprocess.Popen(['your_bash_script', your_variable]).

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? Im so sorry. Im just new to all this and I am so confused at the moment.

Comment: Say you want to pass the number 8 as an argument to your bash script test.sh
Here is what your test.bash should have: 

read -p $1
if $1 == whatever
do something

and your py script should have something like:

myvar = 8
subProcess.Popen(['test.sh', myvar])

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if $1` (the **1st** argument's value) and modify the last line in your `error.py` you should be able to get the result you want.

```
import subprocess as s


file = open("doubt.txt","r") 
Counter = 0
  
# Reading from file 
Content = file.read() 
file.close()
CoList = Content.split("\n") 
  
for i in CoList: 
    if i: 
        Counter += 1
          
#print("This is the number of lines in the file") 
#print(Counter) 

if Counter > 1:
    print("There is some erroneous value. Please restart the scanner")
    s.call(['notify-send', str(Counter), 'Alert!','There is some erroneous value. Please restart the scanner'])
```

```
if $1 > 1
then break
fi
```

You can do this all in about 3 lines instead, will be much simpler:

```
import subprocess as s

with open ("doubt.txt","r") as f:
    if len(f.readlines()) > 1:
        s.call(['notify-send', Counter, 'Alert!','There is some erroneous value. Please restart the scanner'])
```

PS. If you're not going to use the context manager `with` with the `open` function, make sure you use the `close` method on your `file` object.

Comment: Ive tried your method. it returns the following error: File "error.py", line 21, in <module> s.call(['notify-send', Counter, 'Alert!','There is some erroneous value. Please restart the scanner'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 287, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__ restore_signals, start_new_session) File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1295, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int

Comment: Thankyou for your prompt response

Comment: I tried again. It now returns a different error: 2
Invalid number of options.

Comment: cast Count as an int 
s.call(['notify-send', str(Count), ...])

I updated the answer

Comment: The error still persists: Invalid number of options.
./deepscan.sh: 6: ./deepscan.sh: $1: not found

Comment: Im so sorry. I intend to kill the program if the value of Counter is above 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you want to pass a small integer to the calling program. Basically, you have three possibilities, all having drawbacks or advantages.

1. Use the exit code

Provided that the integer is always nonnegative and less than 256, you can pass it back via a Python `exit` and pick it up on the caller side using the variable `$?` which holds the exit code of the most recently executed program.

```
python3 your_program.py
count=$?
```

While this method is simple, I don't recommend it for two reasons:

- Exit codes are intended to communicate errors, not normal data.
- If you one day want to run your script with `set -e` (terminate-on-error), you will be in trouble.

2. Use stdout

Write the integer you want to return to stdout, and pick it up by command substitution, i.e.

```
count=$(python3 your_program.py)
```

Drawback: If you one day want to add additional output to your program (say, for diagnostics), you would have to write it to stderr, otherwise it would pollute your resulting count.

3. Use a file

Have your Python program accept the name of a file, and let it write the count to this file:

```
python3 your_program.py count_file
count=$(<countfile)
```

Drawback: You have to care about the count_files being created, for instance delete them if not needed anymore.